# jqgrid subgrid row_id with spaces not working php jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know subgrid of jqgrid will not work when an id has an space on it right or am wrong? If right is there a possible way to add id with spaces like "New Zealand". My id's our countries. Please see my code.

```
subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var subgrid_table_id, pager_id; subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
        pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
        $("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");
        $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
            datatype: "json",
            width: 500,
            url: "link.php?type="+row_id,
```

Is this possible that **row_id** or subgrid can accept texts with spaces? I dont have any unique keys for this just text. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

the solution is simple, you just need to add a hidden column that can be row number and make that as a key column.

```
colModel: [
     { name: "KeyColumn", formatter: KeyColumn, key: true, hidden: true, } ],
```

and the following function :

```
//KeyColumn
function KeyColumn(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return options.rowId;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ID's cannot contain spaces.

Just [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) them:

```
myID = "New Zealand";

myID = myID.replace(" ", "_");

console.log(myID); // New_Zealand
```

Comment: try this but not working just empty subgrid. New_Zealand was not accepted also by jqgrid.